# What is this kind of interface called in Android and iOS. I want something similar

Tags: android, ios

[image: What is this kind of interface called in Android and iOS. I want something similar]

What is this kind of interface called in Android and iOS. I want something similar

Answer (score 1):

These kind of items are called 'chips'

https://material.io/components/chips/android#using-chips

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/chip/Chip

Comment: Thanks a lot @ARP. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Collection View in iOS or TagCollectionView

To me: TagCollectionView in iOS

https://github.com/zekunyan/TTGTagCollectionView

https://github.com/popodidi/HTagView

https://github.com/pikachu987/Tags